# No water in the Crock pot

Tags: water, crockpot

I have beans cooking in the crock pot and I'm at work. Just realized there is no water. I forgot the water!! What should I expect to come home to?

Comment: Dried beans or canned? What else is in the crock pot? Obviously the safest thing to do is go home ASAP, the water (or other moisture) in the pot is what keeps the temperature of the thing under 212F. I don't know for certain whether it's a fire hazard without liquid in it, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: I have no idea what the spontaneous combustion temp would be for dried beans -- but it might actually be better than if you had canned beans with insufficient liquid.  (as you can use dried beans as pie weights without problem).  With canned beans if the liquid boils off you'd have the possibility of thin deposits of starch from the evaporated liquids, which would more easily burn)  Also if you added sugars (molasses, etc.), you'd have a higher risk of it burning.

Comment: This happened 2 days ago. What did you find at home?

Comment: This happened 3 years ago. What did you find at home?

Comment: @dbmag9 this is scary. On Kristal profile it says "Last seen Sep 17 '15 at 16:59"

Comment: @aaaaaa It's almost like they posted a question and never came back! Maybe they went home to check and the beans exploded leveling a city block!

Answer (score 4):

At best, you'll have toasted beans. At worst they will be burnt. I'm guessing these are dried or otherwise you wouldn't worry. Curious what you find out.